# Trying to retrieve files from external hard drive, but drive is extremely slow

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have been requested to retrieve some files from an old computer.

I tried booting up a laptop to transfer some of these files. To my unfortunate luck I was not able to boot the laptop up because the machine will get stuck at a black screen even before loading up the OS (Windows 7).

I tried to remove the HDD from the laptop and connect it by a SATA to USB cable to my Windows 10 machine. I was able to access the system folders and whatever folders were available on the hard drive, but whenever I try to open the folders, these will open very **slowly**.

My guess is that the hard drive is just either very old causing it to be very slowly, although I am not so sure.

Would anyone happen to know how I could "backup" or retrieve any media and document files from the HDD? Does anyone recognize this issue or has any suggestions regarding solving this problem?

I have already checked the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/322177/folder-access-on-external-hard-drve-is-extremely-slow-and-sometimes-the-folder-a), but these did not help me.

Comment: You could try imaging it to another drive using Macrium Reflect, DriveimageXML using the clone function.

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Possibly the HDD is mounted with USB 1 drivers. Is it consistently slow?

Comment: It is consistently slow but sometimes it is slower than other times. @QuoraFeans

Comment: I am accessing the HDD through my Windows 10 machine @DavidPostill could I do a SMART check through this USB to SATA converter I refered to earlier? I will see if I am able to follow these steps.

Comment: If the smart test program recognises the disk then yes.